# How to get world seed in Realms when you are not the owner?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am playing on an SMP server. One person wants to find a desert, however, I need the seed to use chunkbase.com to see where a desert is. However, the owner has no idea whatsoever of what a seed is. We are on Bedrock edition, and I am not an operator!

Is there any way for me to access the world seed?

Comment: Please bring more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the realm owner and playing in bedrock. This is currently how I located the world seed in v1.20.62.

- when opening minecraft click Play
- under the worlds tab, click on the pencil icon to the right of your realm
- click on the specific world you want to fin the seed in, once click you will see a button appear called Edit World. Click it
- In the World > Game Settings, scroll to the bottom and click Download World
- Once it finished downloading, click Lets Go
- Then go all the way back out to the World tab where you see the list of worlds in your realm. Below your realm you will see the downloaded world. Click the pencil icon next to it
- in the Edit Settings > Game section you will find a field called Seed. This number is your worlds seed number

While in this case you are not the owner, this set of directions would help them locate the seed if they are willing to share it with you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325892)